# Переворот строк через рекурсию

Tags: javascript

Как написать функцию которая переварачивает строку через рекурсию?

Comment: например, с помощью клавиатуры.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно так

```js
const reverse = (str) => {    
    if(str.length == 1 || str.length == 0){
        return str;
    }
    return str[str.length-1] + reverse(str.substr(0, str.length-1));
}
console.info('Reverse: ', reverse('Simple string')); // gnirts elpmiS
```

Подсказка:

```
// *** Что мы в каждой рекурсию передаем?
// str
// st
// s
```

Answer (score 1):

Для этого решения мы будем использовать два встроенных метода: String.prototype.substr() и String.prototype.charAt().

1. Метод **substr()** возвращает указанное количество символов из строки, начиная с указанной позиции. Если не указывать количество символов — вернет все символы, начиная с указанной позиции:
   'hello'.substr(1); // 'ello'
2. Метод **charAt()** возвращает указанный символ из строки:
   'hello'.charAt(0); // 'h'

```js
function reverseString(str) {
  if (str === "") // Условие выхода из рекурсии
    return "";

  else
    return reverseString(str.substr(1)) + str.charAt(0);
  /* 
  Первая часть рекурсивного метода
  Вам нужно помнить, что будет не один вызов функции, а несколько вложенных вызовов
  Each call: str === "?"                           reverseString(str.subst(1))     + str.charAt(0)
  1st call – reverseString("Hello")   will return   reverseString("ello")           + "h"
  2nd call – reverseString("ello")    will return   reverseString("llo")            + "e"
  3rd call – reverseString("llo")     will return   reverseString("lo")             + "l"
  4th call – reverseString("lo")      will return   reverseString("o")              + "l"
  5th call – reverseString("o")       will return   reverseString("")               + "o"

  Вторая часть рекурсивного метода
  Метод попадает в условие if и самый последний вложенный вызов возвращает результат
  5th call will return reverseString("") + "o" = "o"
  4th call will return reverseString("o") + "l" = "o" + "l"
  3rd call will return reverseString("lo") + "l" = "o" + "l" + "l"
  2nd call will return reverserString("llo") + "e" = "o" + "l" + "l" + "e"
  1st call will return reverserString("ello") + "h" = "o" + "l" + "l" + "e" + "h" 
  */
}

reverseString("hello");

console.info(reverseString('hello'));
```

Глубина рекурсии эквивалентна длине строки. Это решение не является лучшим и будет очень медленным, если строка очень длинная.

Comment: Это не рекурсивная функция.

Comment: слово _рекурсия_ вам не знакомо, или вы его пропустили в задаче дважды?

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow, изменил

Comment: @teran, неправильно прочитал вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

Вариант с хвостовой рекурсией, результат накапливается во втором параметре и когда в исходной строке ничего не осталось идет возврат результата.

В противном случае символ добавляется в накапливаемый параметр.

```js
function reverseString(str, result = "") {
  console.log('str: ', str || '""', ', result: ', result || '""');
  if (str === "") // Условие выхода из рекурсии
    return result;

  return reverseString(str.slice(1), str[0] + result);
}

/* 
 Вам нужно помнить, что будет не один вызов функции, а несколько вложенных вызовов
 1st call – reverseString("Hello", "")
 2nd call – reverseString("ello",  "H" + "")
 3rd call – reverseString("llo",   "e" + "H")
 4th call – reverseString("lo",    "l" + "eH")
 5th call – reverseString("o",     "l" + "leH")
 6th call – reverseString("",      "o" + "lleH")
 return "olleH"
*/

console.info(reverseString('Hello'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function reverse(s) {
  return s && s[s.length-1] + reverse(s.slice(0, -1))
}

console.log(reverse("qwe123"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот вариант с дополнительным массивом, однако без всяких индексов

```js
function rev(s) {
  s = Array.isArray(s) ? s : s.split('');
  return s.length ? s.pop() + rev(s) : ''
}

console.log(rev('hello'))
```